# How to configure postfix to permit relaying from some ip address but only using one domain as sender

Tags: postfix

I have been looking for this but I can't find anything. I want to permit one ip address to relay mails by my servers but only using one domain as sender. Can I ? If yes, how. I use postfix 2.9.4. Sorry my english and thanks for any answers.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the domain is a destination or a source address relative to the server you're configuring?

Comment: Yes, I have this domain in virtual_mailbox_domains, How I should to understood 'relative', I know this address, and I want to set server behavior that way that if this ip address try to send some email as fixed sender domain, I allow this. But all mail in this fixed domain I delivery localy

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with.You can specify a user to send mails from an Ip/Host by using sender dependent sasl authentication.
Follow these links.
http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender 
And in other terms.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/postfix-multiple-isp-accounts-smarthost-smtp-client/

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [policy server](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) to accomplish that. That process would receive both the `client_address` address and the `sender` specifying the information that you need to make that determination. The protocol that policy servers need to speak is quite simple.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you for super fast answer, it is not stupid solution but i think that writing, implementation, maintenance separate policy server for 3 customers is little overkill. I hope that exists simplest solution.